Google Security Assessment for Enterprise Only Users (@company.com)
We’re building a web app that requires access to Google Drive and Gmail APIs that fall under the sensitive or restricted scope. The app is for Enterprises Only i.e. all are users will have Google Workspace Email IDs (@company.com). We will allow for both domain wide installation and individual user providing access (but open to limiting to domain wide installation). Do we still need to go through the OAuth Verification Process or External Security Assessment (CASA by an authorized provider)?
At the moment we’re trying to understand the need for such a product and we’d rather not spend on a security assessment.

Is this an internal/private application only for use within YOUR organization? If that's the case then you don't need to have your app verified. If your plan is to offer this web app to organizations outside of your own, then yes, you will likely have to undergo a security assessment as part of the verification process since MOST Google Drive and Gmail API scopes are restricted.

If the web app requires access to Google Drive and Gmail APIs that may fall under the sensitive or restricted scope, it is likely that you will need to go through OAuth verification process and possibly the security assessment, especially if you allow for individual user providing access and not just domain wide installation.

Thanks. Just to get more clarity - I wont need to do it if I limit to domain wide installation?
